# WordPress Trouble

Tags: html, css, wordpress, xhtml

I'm new to WordPress and I'm editing a site for a friend. I'm trying to add a RSS feed to the site so I edited the header.php file (that's where it's going).

I also edited the CSS and then I uploaded it with FileZilla. I refreshed the page and it looks no different.

Here's the HTML: (LinkedIn was there before and it works fine)

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/millermusicllc" target="_blank">
    <div id="linked_in"></div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.millermusiclessons.com/home-page/feed/" target="_blank">
    <div id="rss"></div>
</a>
```

Here's the CSS: (Twitter was there before and it works fine)

```
#twitter{background:url("images/u_tube.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;float:right;height:35px;width:35px;margin:21px 10px 0 0;}
#rss{background:url("images/feed.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;float:right;height:35px;width:35px;margin:21px 10px 0 0;}
```

When I go to the page though and view the source, my HTML isn't there. I have no idea why. Any advice?

The URL is http://www.millermusiclessons.com/

Thanks

Comment: Do you guys possibly have some sort of caching activated? Either via a wp-plugin or an _expires_ header or the like? If the uploaded file has been changed but is not displayed, caching is the most likely cause.

Comment: Are you not able to use the WordPress built in theme editor? You can use it to check the file has been updated.

Comment: @Biotox I checked the built in CSS theme editor and it showed up as the updated version.

Comment: @JohannesPille No idea. How could I check?

Comment: Headers can be checked with the [Live HTTP Headers Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) for instance - which, unfortunately reveals that your Cache is set to `max-age=0` (i.e. no caching). Beats me. Is there a _.user.ini_ in your webserver's root folder? If so check for _apc.enabled_ and _apc.cache_by_default_ and set both to _off_. If that ain't it I'm stumped. Apart from caching, I don't see what could cause this. You could ask your hoster, whether (and how long) they cache, as a last resort.

Comment: Also try cross-posting this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: no user.ini, my host is hostmonster

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The #twitter ID does not seem to be implemented? I would recommend putting the image directly into the code by doing

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/millermusicllc" target="_blank">
<div id="linked_in"><img src="images/u_tube.png" /></div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.millermusiclessons.com/home-page/feed/" target="_blank">
    <div id="rss"><div id="linked_in"><img src="images/feed.gif" /></div>
</a>
```

You would also need to change the css styling to take out the background-image section. Wordpress has an inbuilt editor that I recommend you use. I guarantees that the file really did update and that it was the right file. Also make sure the images are in the right place. For example, if your css files are in a folder called css for example css/style.css, your image path would have to be relative so the section

```
#twitter{background:url("../images/u_tube.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;float:right;height:35px;width:35px;margin:21px 10px 0 0;}
#rss{background:url("../images/feed.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;float:right;height:35px;width:35px;margin:21px 10px 0 0;}
```

Would need a ../ in front to say the parent directory. Let me know if you need a better explanation of this.

Comment: Well the page has YouTube, FB, and LinkenIn links at the top. I'm trying to add an RSS the same way. The LinkedIn HTML has CSS exactly like the RSS CSS, but with the link and div name changed. Twitter isn't actually one of the links. The guy who made the site originally decided to name the YouTube div Twitter. The site had a lot of mistakes like that, but I've fixed most of them. My CSS is in the same folder as the rest of the pages and the images are working for the other links, so I don't think that's the problem (../) -unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Even if all of the above were needed to be done, it wouldn't be relevant to the question. The OP's HTML from _header.php_ should appear no matter what - even if it breaks the page, it should at least do that...